# Padding / bg-color issue in all the per site meta - activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, per-site-meta, activity

In all the per site metas, on the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2451726/arulkumar?tab=topactivity) - REPUTATION section, the reputation score is displayed with the `background color: #eff0f1`. So it looks like the "top n% period" link is *(200+ reputation sites only)*  displaying without the proper margin.

When inspecting the element of the div, CSS class `bg-black-050` contains the background color, that caused the display issue. The same class is not applied in the main sites.

Can be the `bg-black-050` be removed from the reputation DIV, or the "top n% period" added with a proper margin?

Screenshot from Meta Stack Overflow:

> [image: Reputation]

Comment: [answer on SOmeta regarding that padding issue..](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381230/the-top-x-overall-text-needs-more-padding/381231#381231)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The different background color on the meta profile rep has been removed, resolving this issue.

---

> Why does meta rep
> need a different highlight?
> Answer: it doesn’t

Comment: We seem to have multiple differences in how many syllables we use when pronouncing things xD I love the haikus though!